# Docker/Flask: Development server runs on localhost fine, but cannot access external URL

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm brand new to Docker so I think there's something wrong in my setup.

Here's my `app.py` (reduced version):

```
import flask
from flask import request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def index():
    return('Home')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /app

ENV FLASK_APP=app.py

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "app.py"]
```

I'm building the image with `docker build -t flaskapi .` and running with
`docker run --rm -it -p 80:5000 flaskapi` which gives the following output:

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: development
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
```

Visiting `localhost` in the browser, everything works fine but when trying to vist `http://172.17.0.2:5000/` or testing with Postman, I eventually get a timeout error. I feel like it's just a small mistake I've made somewhere but I can't quite see it. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Docker runs in a separate subnet that is not accessible by the outside world. To be able to access the service running inside the container, you will have to map one of your host's ports to the internal docker subnet.

In your run command, you map TCP 80 to TCP 5000 inside the docker network (the  `-p 80:5000` part). That's why your service is accessible when visiting `http://localhost` (80 is implied). In essence, any request to your port 80 will end up being served by the service running at  `http://172.17.0.2:5000/`.

The `172.*` ip is in Docker's subnet range. To communicate via that, with your current settings, you would have to be in another container that shares the same network as this one.

Comment: I see, it looks like I had a misunderstanding of how Docker works. So actually, if I can visit ```http://localhost``` fine then everything's working as intended. And then to actually have said container hosted somewhere I'd have to use something like Heroku then?

Comment: @AdamMinas, can I take away from your answer that observing Flask running on all addresses (0.0.0.0) + on 127.0.0.1:5001 + on 172.17.0.2:5001 is not redundant/over the top/too much? I can ping the latter connections with `nmap` inside the container, and browse 127.0.0.1:5001 from host (via docker port mapping). The latter is what I wanted, but I am a little bewildered whether flask runs on more addresses than necessary for that purpose.